# Update two column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have Oracle 11g. I want to update two column for two different `where` conditions.

For example

```
update table 
set col1 = 'name' where col2= '100'
    col3 = 'sal' where col4 = 'id';
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a `CASE`:

```
update your_table set
  col1 = case when col2 = '100' then 'name' end,
  col3 = case when col4 = 'id' then 'sal' end;
```

Example you posted doesn't say what to do if `col2` and `col4` don't contain those values. Also, without `where` clause, you'd update the whole table so *maybe* it (the `update` statement) lacks in additional

```
where col2 = '100' 
  and col4 = 'id'
```

---

As you commented, you want to change gender.

```
update your_table set
  gender = case when gender = 'male' then 'female'
                when gender = 'female' then 'male'
           end;
```

Or, with `decode` (presuming there are only *male* and *female* genders in that table):

```
update your_table set
  gender = decode(gender, 'male', 'female', 'male');
```

Comment: Actually in gender column if there is female replace it with male and if there is male replace it with female

Comment: Why didn't you say so? I edited the answer and added some more code. Have a look, please.

Comment: To be equal to update with the`where` clause there should be the same column in the `else` branch: `set col1 = case when col2 = '100' then 'name' else col1 end`

Comment: Right, @astentx, if that's what they wanted. Anyway, it looks that the whole problem is in "changing gender", as the OP commented, not those *dummy* irrelevant values in the original example.

Comment: I've done something rather unusual.  I upvoted the answer because it is correct and doesn't deserve a downvote.  I also voted to close the question, because it is clearly not what the OP is really asking.